# Messed up magento database indexes

Tags: database, performance, index

Probably due to errors during reindexing, our store got really slow. Reindexing didn't solve it. I activated query log to identify which ones take are slower.

Following is one of them. How could I possibly repair this mess?

> SQL: SELECT `e`.*, `core_url_rewrite`.`request_path`,
>   IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value,
>   at_is_active_default.value) AS `is_active` FROM
>   `catalog_category_entity` AS `e`  LEFT JOIN `core_url_rewrite` ON
>   (core_url_rewrite.category_id=e.entity_id) AND
>   (core_url_rewrite.is_system=1 AND core_url_rewrite.store_id='2' AND
>   core_url_rewrite.id_path LIKE 'category/%')  INNER JOIN
>   `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_is_active_default` ON
>   (`at_is_active_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND
>   (`at_is_active_default`.`attribute_id` = '42') AND
>   `at_is_active_default`.`store_id` = 0  LEFT JOIN
>   `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_is_active` ON
>   (`at_is_active`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND
>   (`at_is_active`.`attribute_id` = '42') AND (`at_is_active`.`store_id`
>   = 2) WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '3') AND (IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value, at_is_active_default.value) = '1') AND (`e`.`entity_id` IN('4', '5', '6', '7', '9', '56', '66', '93', '94',
>   '95', '103', '110', '111', '313', '314', '452')) ORDER BY
>   `e`.`position` ASC

AFF: 16

TIME: 25.8226

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com or here.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: To improve your MySQL response time, please provide Additional information requested Dec 18, 18.  Thanks